# Quick Sort picking the Right Median Recursion Max

Tags: python, quicksort

This is my code for a quick sort that picks the right most value as the pivot:

```
def qsort_right(self, array):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    last_value = len(array) - 1

    if len(array) > 1:
        pivot = array[last_value]
        for i in array:
            if i < pivot:
               less.append(i)
            if i == pivot:
               equal.append(i)
            if i > pivot:
                greater.append(i)
        return self.qsort_right(less)+equal+self.qsort_right(greater)
    else:
        return array
```

I have three arrays I want sorted.  All 3 are of size 10,000.  The first one is random, the second is sorted by 20% and the third is sorted by 40%.  The sort works for the first two, but for the third I get the error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can some one please explain to me why this is happening?  I thought since the size of all three of the arrays are the same, if one works then they all work.

Here is the code I used to create the 40% sorted array that the quick sort doesnt work on:

```
class forty_array():
def __init__(self, size):
    self.forty_array = []
    self.ordered = []
    self.size = size
    self.ordered_keys()

def ordered_keys(self):
    i = 0
    value = 10
    while i < 4000: #for the 20% sorted array, this number is 2000
        value = value + random.randint(0, 450)
        self.ordered.append(value)
        i = i+1

def fill_array(self):
    i = self.size

    while i > 0:
        self.forty_array.append(random.randint(0, 100))
        i = i-1

    j = 0
    k = 0

    while j < 4000: #for the 20% sorted array, this number is 2000
        self.forty_array[k] = self.ordered[j]
        k = k + random.randint(0, 2) #for the 20% sorted array, this number is 5, not 2
        j = j+1

def retreive_array(self):
    self.fill_array()
    return self.forty_array
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are always choosing the right most value of your array you have a O(N^2) worst case for already sorted arrays, each recursion will reduce the problem size only by 1.
So at a certain level of "sortedness" you will hit the python recursion depth limit.

The choice of the pivot is important to avoid the quicksort worst case for real world data. Common are chosing the median of the first the last and the middle element, but there are many variations. Keep in mind that regardless of (constant time) pivot choice you can always construct a dataset that will trigger the quick sort worst case. This can lead to denial of service attacks in you applications.

To avoid the worst case completely you need to use different algorithm, introsort, heapsort or merge sort are examples for better worst case sorting algorithms.

Comment: Can you explain why it only happens with the 40% and not the 20%?  I added edits to show how the 20% was made.  Very similar to the 40%.

Comment: for uniformly distributed data quicksort will on average need to recurse about log2(N) times as the pivot choice will randomly divide the dataset in half, if the data is sorted the right pivot will always divide it into N -1 / 1 so you need to recurse about N times, if its partially sorted the recursion is something between the optimum and the worst case, your 20% case happens to be below python limit and 40% above. You can rewrite quicksort to not use recursion then it will always work, but the bad pivot choice will still lead to bad performance.

Comment: How would I write quick sort without using recursion?